# Clear all items in a ListFragment

Tags: android, android-listfragment

I am using a ListFragment and display a dynamic list from a database, I want to update the view and change the order of the list by running the ASYNCTASK again. At them moment when this is done the new data just gets put on the bottom of the current list.

*asynctask in fragment:*

creates the list adapter and displays it

```
        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
        // // dismiss the dialog once done
        pDialog.dismiss();

        fragment_module.this.getListView().invalidateViews(); //does nothing
         adapter = new SimpleAdapter(getActivity(),
                questionsList, R.layout.questionlistitem, new String[] {
                        TAG_QUESTIONVOTE, TAG_QUESTIONTEXT,
                        TAG_QUESTIONANSWER, CONCATINATED_SUBMISSION,
                        TAG_QUESTIONID }, new int[] { R.id.upvoteText,
                        R.id.questionText, R.id.questionAnswer,
                        R.id.submission, R.id.qid });
        // updating listview

        setListAdapter(adapter);

    }
```

The view is to change after an onclick event is just want the list to be cleared so it can update.

**update**
Code called to update view and re-run asynctask

```
                      fragment_module.this.getListView().invalidateViews();
                  getQuestionList obj2 = new getQuestionList();
                    obj2.execute();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use something like

```
collection.clear();
listview.getAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: let me get this straight , because i am little confused ... you create a listview with values from database ... and then later you want to update listview items with new values from databse, but you dont want to append all of them at the end of listview but at position as you want ? :)

Comment: Oh right no I want to completely reload the list with new values from the database. The code i have at the moment just adds the values to the current list. I'm trying a null adapter at the moment to try and see if that works

Comment: in that case jusr use an ArrayAdapter ... and the collection is an ArrayList that contains values that you want to display passed as a last argument in constructor when creating an ArrayAdaper

Comment: Took some time to get back to it but is now fixed thanks for the help